# PROPAGATION_REQUIRED behavior in spring?

Tags: java, spring, transactional

I have few questions on PROPAGATION_REQUIRED behaviour which i am not able to clarify on [Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).

**Scenario1:-**

```
@Transactional
method1(){
// do some update without exception
}
```

Data will be committed as thread comes out of method1. Right ?

**Scenario2:-**

```
@Transactional
method1(){
// do some update without exception
method2();
}

@Transactional
method2(){
// do some update without exception
}
```

Data will be committed as thread comes out of method1. Right ?

**Scenario3:-**

```
@Transactional
method1(){
// do some update without exception
method2();
}

@Transactional
method2(){
 // some update in DB 
 throw new RunTimeException()
}
```

Nothing will be commited. Right ?

**Scenario4:-**

```
@Transactional
method1(){
// do some update without exception
method2();
}

@Transactional
method2(){
 // some update in DB 
 throw new SomeCheckedException()
}
```

whole transaction will be committed as thread comes out of method1 as checked exception
is thrown. Though i could change this behaviour with `@Transactional(rollbackFor=SomeCheckedException.class)` Right ?

Please let me know if above understanding is correct.

Comment: Yes, you're right on above behaviours. You should carefull only for unchecked exceptions that will rollbacked anyway in your case.

Comment: Scenario 3 and 4 are the same; my guess is you wanted the `@Transactional` annotation once on `method1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, checked exceptions don't automatically rollback the active transaction; only unchecked  `RuntimeException` do.

If you want rollback for certain checked exceptions, you can use `@Transactional(rollbackFor=SomeCheckedException.class)`

Note: `@Transactional` has no effect when you call the method internally:

```
method1(){
  method2();
}

@Transactional
method2(){
  // some update in DB -> fails because there is no transaction
}
```

The annotation can only be applied when Spring can wrap the method call.

Comment: Thanks .As you said "Transactional has no effect when you call the method internally", It means in those cases @Transactional  has to be applied on outermost method (in this case method1). Correct ?

Comment: @MSach: The rule is: If you use `this.method()` to call, then `@Transactional` doesn't apply. If you use `bean.method()`, then it is.